# Extra hour when given milliseconds to date filter

Tags: angularjs

I want to setup a countdown on a template, so I have a counter in my $scope named time_counter, which value is a certain number of milliseconds, let's say 5000ms for this example.

When I try to display this number as a number of hours, minutes and seconds in my template, it tells me 01h00m05s instead of 00h00m05s. Here is how I proceed:

```
{{ 5000 | date:'HH:mm:ss' }}
```

Is it a known bug or is my syntax bad ?

Here is the fiddle : [Date filter problem](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/2884/)

I use Angularjs 1.0.3

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The date filter (according to the documentation) assumes that the timezone of the given date is relative to **UTC** if none is given so what your getting is the time as it relates to utc from your given milliseconds. If you change this to a format like 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss you'll see this effect in a more pronounced way as it will be relative to 1969 on a testing version this prints '12-31-1969 17:00:05' for me.

To get the result your looking for you'll want to create a custom filter for this which is a time counter filter. You can follow the tutorial at http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09 which will step you through it's creation.